# How can I render text without any HTTP HEAD information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, http-headers, rendering

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2 and I would like to render some response text *without any HTTP HEAD* information. I tryed to use `render :text => "MY_CUSTOM_TEXT"` in my controller as states the [Official Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

> (From "2.2.7 Rendering Text" chapter) You can send plain text – with no markup at all – back to the browser by using the :text option to render: `render :text => "OK"`

but the response still contains HTTP HEAD data.

How can I render the response so that it is just the text `MY_CUSTOM_TEXT`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some kind of head data is going to be returned no matter what; that's part of the HTTP protocol, and not something rails or any other framework can turn off.

What exactly is the underlying problem you're trying to solve? What issue is the HEAD information causing you?

Comment: I would like to respond just wth text because another server (that has *not* a browser) have to parse that text "byte by byte".

Comment: The server acting as an http client should probably use an http client library that can separate the head content from the body content, and just parse the the body portion of the response "byte by byte". That part should be limited to whatever you pass to 'render :text'. You might also consider having it fetch JSON or XML content, or even using SOAP depending on your situation.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "that part should be limited to whatever you pass to 'render :text'"?

Comment: I mean that the body portion of the HTTP response should have just the text that you pass to 'render :text', such as 'MY_CUSTOM_TEXT' in your example. You need an http client library to get just the body portion of the response.